# DataTable change properties with Media Query

Tags: javascript, datatable

I want to change the **scrollX** property of my DataTable to true when switched to mobile but I don't know how to do that, I have tried using *media query* but it does not seem to work. Any idea?

```js
var mobview = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 425px)" );
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "ajax": "src/json/AttendanceReport.json",
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "FullName" },
            { "data": "DaysPresent" },
            { "data": "DaysAbsent" },
            {"data":"DaysLate"}
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
    
    if (mobview.matches) {
        table.scrollX=true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mobview = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 425px)" );
    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": !mobview.matches,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "ajax": "src/json/AttendanceReport.json",
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "FullName" },
            { "data": "DaysPresent" },
            { "data": "DaysAbsent" },
            {"data":"DaysLate"}
        ],
       "order": [[1, 'asc']]
 });
```

**EDIT**

[matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) method returns a object that can then be used to determine if the document matches the media query string.

```
mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia(mediaQueryString)
```

Where [mediaQueryString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) stores information on a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries).

You can invoke multiple mediaQueryString as well, Let say an example

```
const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('(min-width: Xpx), (max-height: Ypx)');
```

It will result in output as follows

```
MediaQueryList {media: "not all, not all", matches: false, onchange: null}
```

Description of output ([MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList))

1. media - A DOMString representing a serialized media query.
2. matches - Bolean (true/False)